# Input type file multiple not work on android

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an issue with multiple input file selection on android, I use input HTML form like this.

```
<input type="file" id="multipleLocalFilesSelector" nv-file-select uploader="uploader" multiple="multiple" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" style="visibility:hidden">
```

everything works fine except the multiple attribute. I couldn't find any way to be able to select multiple file, it keep making me select single file.
Does anyone have solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature seems not to be supported on Android Browsers:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple

Comment: Yes its also know bug in ionic

Answer (score 1):

Update ionic version of app to 6. Remove and add platform again. Multiple file selection will start working. It seems to be an issue of android versions less than 8. Just make sure you are using name="file[]".